# Eclipse Plugin default font

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an eclipse plugin for windows and linux environments and I want to insure the look and feel is similar between platforms.  One thing that is annoying me is the fonts between platforms are different sizes, so something that looks sized well in one platform looks bad in another.

Is there a way to set the default font and font size for a plugin?  I suspect I can change something in plugin_customization.ini but do not know what.

Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

To use plugin_customization.ini you have to create an [eclipse Product](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_Eclipse_product%3F) and then you can create a plugin_customization.ini to override whatever preferences you wish.

If you can't create and distribute an Eclipse product you can override preferences from your Eclipse plugin by adding a `startup extension point` for your plugin class and perform your preference overrides in the `IStartup#earlyStartup` method.  However, this could be considered bad form and users would not expect that by just installing a new plugin it would modify its preferences, so be careful if you go this route.